# I need help with Expanding logs

Tags: logarithms

I know the log rules for expanding but I am not sure how to expand these difficult ones: (also the x's here depending upon the context are multiplication)

$$\log_4(x^4yz)^2$$

$$\log_3 (((6\times 5)^2)/11)^2$$

$$\log_2(d \sqrt[3]{abc})$$

$$\log ((3\times 5)/8^3)^2$$

Comment: Please use * to denote multplication, or even better use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: @Trent I have formatted your question. Please double-check to ensure that I have correctly transcribed the expressions.

Comment: The King will not complete all without seeing what has been attempted.

Comment: Thanks! That is correctly edited.

Comment: @Trent : Note that your notation is a bit ambiguous ; you seem to write $\log_4(x^4yz)^2$ to mean $\log_4( (x^4yz)^2 )$, which is really not the same as $(\log_4(x^4yz))^2$. Without a context, I would've read you wrong.

Comment: The downvote was completely unjustified. I +1'ed to compensate...

Answer (score 1):

If you know the log rules, you also need the rules for exponents, then just apply them.  For example $$\log_4(x^4yz)^2=\log_4(x^8y^2z^2)=\log_4(x^8)+\dots=8\log_4x+\dots$$  The same approach works on all the rest

Comment: Thanks! So I see that the exponents apply first then the log rules.

Comment: You could do it the other way, as well $$\log_4(x^4yz)^2=2\log_4(x^4yz)=$$  Both are legal, sometimes one is more helpful, sometimes the other.

Comment: Thanks! How about the 3rd problem? The other two seem to be answered by your answer.

Comment: The cube root is just the $\frac 13$ power

Comment: Ah makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Trent consider mark the question as solved